# Celery custom task with extra parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Im currently working on a project with many celery tasks and each one with complicated retry rules.

We configure `max_retries` and `retry_backoffice` using env vars and if `max_retries` was exceeded then we place the message in a "fallback queue" like `example_task.apply_async(queue=settings.EXAMPLE_FALLBACK_QUEUE, kwargs=kwargs)`. The problem is that we are duplicating tons of code and messing our tasks with code like:

```py
@app.task
def example_task(**kwargs):
    try:
         ''' The real task business '''
         ...
    except Exception as e:
         # Here we have some logs
         # Also some checks about the nature of e and how to proceed

         # some cases we run:
         example_task.retry(
            exc=e, max_retries=max_retries, countdown=countdown
         )

         # and other cases we have
         example_task.apply_async(queue=settings.example_task_fallback_queue, kwargs=kwargs)
```

My idea is to extend `celery.Task` class with some extra params and do something like this:

```py
@app.task(@app.task(ignore_result=False, bind=True, base=RetryTask(place_an_order_config))
def example_task(kwargs):
    '''Just the real business here'''
```

and implementa a class like:

```py
@dataclass
class RetryConfig:
    fallback_queue: str
    max_retries: int
    retry_backoff: int
    event_name: str
    traced_exceptions: List[Any]


class RetryTask(celery.Task):
    def __init__(self, config: RetryConfig):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.run(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if e in self.config.traced_exceptions:
                # Logs
                return

            # And here implement the retry/fallback logic
            # Using the parameterization attr `self.config` to
            # setup
```

The problem is that the arg `base` in `app.task` expects a class ( and celery internally instanciates the class ) not an object, so I changed the `RetryTask` class to something like this:

```py
class RetryTask:  # Dont inhirit directly from celery.Task
    def __init__(self, config: RetryConfig):
        self = celery.Task()
        self.config = config

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.run(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if e in self.config.traced_exceptions:
                # Logs
                return

            # And here implement the retry/fallback logic
            # Using the parameterization attr `self.config` to
            # setup
```

That way I can pass a `RetryTask` object to `app.task` decorator and parametrize my task.
Unfortunately the above code is throwing `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases` when the `app.task` function checks `task = type(fun.__name__, (base,), dict(...)`.

So my question is: How can I parametrize my custom `RetryTask` class the right way ?